# Slick table renaming in subqueries

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I'm trying to use a subquery in slick 3 to delete rows from a table that has a compound key on (key:String, ts: Timestamp) in a way that it would delete old records, but keep at least one for each key. It's almost getting it right from this scala code:

`tq` here is a `TableQuery` against the table "a" and
`minTimestamp` is a timestamp before which records should be deleted:

```scala
tq.filter(row => (row.ts < minTimestamp && row.ts =!= (
  tq.filter(filterRow => filterRow.key === row.key).map(_.ts).max
))).delete
```

but when doing the subquery it's not renaming the table and deletes all rows except the max(ts) for the whole table. The query it generates is:

```scala
delete from "a" where ("a"."ts" < '2016-10-31 13:53:39.203') and (not (
  "a"."ts" = (select max("ts") from "a" where "a"."key" = "a"."key")
))
```

How can I make it rename the table in the subquery so that the query would be something like:

```scala
delete from "a" where ("a"."ts" < '2016-10-31 13:53:39.203') and (not (
  "a"."ts" = (select max("ts") from "a" as "x" where "x"."key" = "a"."key")
))
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in the generated SQL. Your Scala code looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks, @jkinkead I'll file a bug with slick then.